# Symfony2 Embedded Forms one to many relationship

Tags: php, forms, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a doubt w.r.t Embedded Forms. I have a "Properties" entity which has 2 fields "id" and "name" and "Amenities" entity which has 2 fields "id" and "value"(id=1,value=wifi,id=2,value=water,id=3,value=food).I have created these 2 entities,but now I want to save the id of "Properties" and "Amenities" into a separate 3rd table.So, I have created a third entity "Properties_Amenities" and its table "properties_amenities".I have created a "one to many" relationship as shown below.I want to embed "Amenities" into "Properties" with the click of an "Add Amenities" button on the "Properties Form".I am not sure as to where to place the "addAmenities()" and "removeAmenities()" functions in the Entity files. Below are 3 entities:-

Properties.php

```
<?php

namespace EpitaEvents\FormBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Properties
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="properties")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Properties
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Properties_Amenities", mappedBy="properties",cascade={"persist"})
 **/
private $properties_amenities1;

public function __construct() {
    $this->properties_amenities1 = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Get id 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Get properties_amenities1  
 */
public function getProperties_Amenities1() 
{
    return $this->properties_amenities1;
}

/**
 * Set properties_amenities1  
 *  
 */
public function setProperties_Amenities1($properties_amenities1)
{
    $this->properties_amenities1 = $properties_amenities1;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Add Amenities
 * 
 * @return Properties
 */
public function addAmenities(\EpitaEvents\FormBundle\Entity\Properties_Amenities $amenities) 
{
    $amenities->setProperties($this);
    $this->amenities[] = $amenities;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove Amenities
 * 
 */
public function removeAmenities(\EpitaEvents\FormBundle\Entity\Properties_Amenities $amenities) {
    $this->amenities->removeElement($amenities);
}
}
```

Amenities.php

```
<?php

namespace EpitaEvents\FormBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Amenities
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="amenities")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Amenities
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string", length=100)
 */
private $value;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Properties_Amenities", mappedBy="amenities")
 **/
private $properties_amenities2;

public function __construct() {
    $this->properties_amenities2 = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set value
 *
 * @param string $value
 * @return Amenities
 */
public function setValue($value)
{
    $this->value = $value;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get value
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getValue()
{
    return $this->value;
}

/**
 * Set Properties
 * 
 */
public function setProperties_Amenities2($properties_amenities2) 
{
    $this->properties_amenities2 = $properties_amenities2;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get Properties
 * 
 * @return EpitaEvents\FormBundle\Entity\Properties
 */
public function getProperties_Amenities2() 
{
    return $this->properties_amenities2;
}
}
```

(Also should the __construct() be put in these 2 above files or in "Properties_Amenities.php"(Below)???)
Properties_Amenities.php

```
<?php

namespace EpitaEvents\FormBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Properties_Amenities
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="properties_amenities")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */

class Properties_Amenities
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Properties", inversedBy="properties_amenities1")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="properties_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $properties;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Amenities", inversedBy="properties_amenities2")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="amenities_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $amenities; 

function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

function getProperties() {
    return $this->properties;
}

function getAmenities() {
    return $this->amenities;
}

function setProperties($properties) {
    $this->properties = $properties;
}

function setAmenities($amenities) {
    $this->amenities = $amenities;
}
}
```

Can any one suggest as to where to place the "addAmenities()" and "removeAmenities()" functions as I want to save the "id's" of "Properties.php" and "Amenities.php" in a "SEPARATE, THIRD" Entity and table??

Comment: This is a large amount of code; can you possible narrow it down to the code that is relevant to the question?

Comment: I wanted to know how to save the "Properties" and "Amenities" id in  a Third,Separate Entity "Properties_Amenities" and where to write the __construct() methods etc??Are these correct in the above entitites??Are the "addEntities()" and "removeEntities()" method written in the correct entity i.e in "Properties.php"??